# How to declare numeric variables?

Tags: excel, vba

Numeric variables give

> Run Time 6` error

It all seems to be related to the way Excel on MacOs handles these declarations. I find with `Integer`, `Single`, and `Double` if you do a division you get the error.

```vb
    Dim x, y as double
    x=2
    y=2 'error 6
    x=x/2
    y=y/2  'error6 
    
End Sub
```

If you put `x` and `y` in `Watch` window you will see they are not showing as `Double`; instead, `x` is displayed as `Variant/String`, `y` as `String`.

The `Variant/String` performs ok, the string does not.

MS Docs state that `Dim x,y As Double` will declare both to be doubles. Others, who I assume are on Windows, say not, that you must say `Dim x As Double, y As Double`; but in this case, even that does not work.

MacOs Excel Version 16.43

Comment: I've had related problems with DATE, SINGLE and INTEGER. Variables on MAC seem to always go to variant/string or string. Only variant/string will act as you expect in arithmetic etc.

Comment: `Dim x, y as double` does not mean `Dim x as double, y as double` it means `Dim x as variant, y as double`

Comment: Further to @braX 's point, I do not see how `y=2` would raise an error as `Double`s should be able to handle a value of `2`. Also, please try to copy and paste the actual code that's giving you an error rather than type it in your post.

Comment: Please show us where the MS Docs it states `that Dim x,y As Double will declare both to be doubles`.

Comment: Yes I later discovered I was looking at VB doc not VBA. But how unconventional and wasted coding to require “as” for every variable. Even MS VB doesn’t require that nonsense. As a former FORTRAN and Basic programmer I find the VBA documentation totally inadequate b

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax:

```vb
Dim x As Double
Dim y As Double

x = 2
y = 2
x = x / 2
y = y / 2

' No error.
```